# java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect Error while Installing APK

Tags: android

I got an error in android while running. It is

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect Error while Installing APK.
```

Please some one help me what happen and how to fix.

The error show in log is.

```
Connection attempts: 1
09:43:16 'C:\Users\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe,start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
```

The error show in Run console

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
Error while Installing APK
```

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 3):

kill the adb.exe process,and restart androidstudio